Make leds accessible from hid device
i have a winwing rudder peddal which has three leds, but the leds are not direct accessible from usb hid evdev and
/sys/bus/hid/devices/0003:xxxx/input/inputxx/capabilities/led
reports 0.
The report decriptor is:
0x05, 0x01,        // Usage Page (Generic Desktop Ctrls)
0x09, 0x04,        // Usage (Joystick)
0xA1, 0x01,        // Collection (Application)
0x85, 0x01,        //   Report ID (1)
0x05, 0x09,        //   Usage Page (Button)
0x19, 0x01,        //   Usage Minimum (0x01)
0x29, 0x0F,        //   Usage Maximum (0x0F)
0x15, 0x00,        //   Logical Minimum (0)
0x25, 0x01,        //   Logical Maximum (1)
0x35, 0x00,        //   Physical Minimum (0)
0x45, 0x01,        //   Physical Maximum (1)
0x75, 0x01,        //   Report Size (1)
0x95, 0x0F,        //   Report Count (15)
0x81, 0x02,        //   Input (Data,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position)
0x75, 0x01,        //   Report Size (1)
0x95, 0x01,        //   Report Count (1)
0x81, 0x01,        //   Input (Const,Array,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position)
0x05, 0x01,        //   Usage Page (Generic Desktop Ctrls)
0x09, 0x33,        //   Usage (Rx)
0x15, 0x00,        //   Logical Minimum (0)
0x27, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00,  //   Logical Maximum (65534)
0x35, 0x00,        //   Physical Minimum (0)
0x47, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00,  //   Physical Maximum (65534)
0x75, 0x10,        //   Report Size (16)
0x95, 0x01,        //   Report Count (1)
0x81, 0x02,        //   Input (Data,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position)
0x05, 0x01,        //   Usage Page (Generic Desktop Ctrls)
0x09, 0x34,        //   Usage (Ry)
0x15, 0x00,        //   Logical Minimum (0)
0x27, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00,  //   Logical Maximum (65534)
0x35, 0x00,        //   Physical Minimum (0)
0x47, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00,  //   Physical Maximum (65534)
0x75, 0x10,        //   Report Size (16)
0x95, 0x01,        //   Report Count (1)
0x81, 0x02,        //   Input (Data,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position)
0x05, 0x01,        //   Usage Page (Generic Desktop Ctrls)
0x09, 0x35,        //   Usage (Rz)
0x15, 0x00,        //   Logical Minimum (0)
0x27, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00,  //   Logical Maximum (65534)
0x35, 0x00,        //   Physical Minimum (0)
0x47, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00,  //   Physical Maximum (65534)
0x75, 0x10,        //   Report Size (16)
0x95, 0x01,        //   Report Count (1)
0x81, 0x02,        //   Input (Data,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position)
0x85, 0x02,        //   Report ID (2)
0x06, 0xFF, 0x00,  //   Usage Page (Reserved 0xFF)
0x09, 0x01,        //   Usage (0x01)
0x15, 0x00,        //   Logical Minimum (0)
0x26, 0xFF, 0x00,  //   Logical Maximum (255)
0x35, 0x00,        //   Physical Minimum (0)
0x46, 0xFF, 0x00,  //   Physical Maximum (255)
0x75, 0x08,        //   Report Size (8)
0x95, 0x0D,        //   Report Count (13)
0x81, 0x02,        //   Input (Data,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position)
0x09, 0x02,        //   Usage (0x02)
0x91, 0x02,        //   Output (Data,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position,Non-volatile)
0xC0,              // End Collection

I can switch on and dimm the leds with direct endpoint write
import usb.core
import usb.util

from enum import Enum

class Leds(Enum):
    LEFT = 0
    RIGHT = 1
    LEFT_AND_RIGHT = 2
    LOGO = 3

device = usb.core.find(idVendor=0x4098, idProduct=0xbef0)
if device is None:
    raise RuntimeError('Device not found')
interface = device[0].interfaces()[0]
if device.is_kernel_driver_active(interface.bInterfaceNumber):
    device.detach_kernel_driver(interface.bInterfaceNumber)

endpoints = device[0].interfaces()[0].endpoints()
print(endpoints)
endpoint = endpoints[1]
print(endpoint)


led = Leds.LOGO
brightness = 120

data = [0x02, 0xf0, 0xbe, 0, 0, 3, 0x49, led.value, brightness, 0,0,0,0,0]
cmd = bytes(data)
endpoint.write(cmd)

but i have to detach the kernel driver, so I can no longer receive hid events.
I testes to write a small kernel driver, similar to https://github.com/igorinov/linux-winwing and add the leds there. But the leds are still not accessible. Do I have to modify the descriptor to access them? How to do this?
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-2.0

/*
 * HID driver for WinWing Orion 2 throttle
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2023 Ivan Gorinov
 */

#include <linux/device.h>
#include <linux/hid.h>
#include <linux/hidraw.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/mutex.h>

#define MAX_REPORT 16

struct winwing_led {
    struct led_classdev cdev;
    struct hid_device *hdev;
    int number;
};

struct winwing_led_info {
    int number;
    int max_brightness;
    const char *led_name;
};

static struct winwing_led_info led_info[4] = {
    { 0, 255, "left" },
    { 1, 255, "right" },
    { 2, 255, "left_right" },
    { 3, 255, "logo" },
};


struct winwing_drv_data {
    struct hid_device *hdev;
    const __u8 *remap;
    __u8 *report_buf;
    struct mutex lock;
    unsigned int num_leds;
    struct winwing_led leds[];
};

static int winwing_led_write(struct led_classdev *cdev, enum led_brightness br)
{
    struct winwing_led *led = (struct winwing_led *) cdev;
    struct winwing_drv_data *data = hid_get_drvdata(led->hdev);
    __u8 *buf = data->report_buf;
    int ret;

    mutex_lock(&data->lock);

    buf[0] = 0x02;
    buf[1] = 0xf0;
    buf[2] = 0xbe;
    buf[3] = 0x00;
    buf[4] = 0x00;
    buf[5] = 0x03;
    buf[6] = 0x49;
    buf[7] = led->number;
    buf[8] = br;
    buf[9] = 0x00;
    buf[10] = 0;
    buf[11] = 0;
    buf[12] = 0;
    buf[13] = 0;

    ret = hid_hw_output_report(led->hdev, buf, 14);

    mutex_unlock(&data->lock);

    return ret;
}

static int winwing_init_led(struct hid_device *hdev, struct input_dev *input)
{
    struct winwing_drv_data *data;
    struct winwing_led *led;
    int ret;
    int i;

    data = hid_get_drvdata(hdev);

    if (!data)
        return -EINVAL;

    data->report_buf = devm_kmalloc(&hdev->dev, MAX_REPORT, GFP_KERNEL);

    if (!data->report_buf)
        return -ENOMEM;

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        struct winwing_led_info *info = &led_info[i];

        led = &data->leds[i];
        led->hdev = hdev;
        led->number = info->number;
        led->cdev.max_brightness = info->max_brightness;
        led->cdev.brightness_set_blocking = winwing_led_write;
        led->cdev.flags = LED_HW_PLUGGABLE;
        led->cdev.name = devm_kasprintf(&hdev->dev, GFP_KERNEL,
                        "%s::%s",
                        dev_name(&input->dev),
                        info->led_name);

        ret = devm_led_classdev_register(&hdev->dev, &led->cdev);
        if (ret)
            return ret;
    }

    return ret;
}

static int winwing_probe(struct hid_device *hdev,
            const struct hid_device_id *id)
{
    struct winwing_drv_data *data;
    size_t data_size = struct_size(data, leds, 3);
    int ret;

    ret = hid_parse(hdev);
    if (ret) {
        hid_err(hdev, "parse failed\n");
        return ret;
    }

    data = devm_kzalloc(&hdev->dev, data_size, GFP_KERNEL);

    if (!data)
        return -ENOMEM;

    hid_set_drvdata(hdev, data);

    ret = hid_hw_start(hdev, HID_CONNECT_DEFAULT);
    if (ret) {
        hid_err(hdev, "hw start failed\n");
        return ret;
    }

    return 0;
}

static int winwing_input_configured(struct hid_device *hdev,
            struct hid_input *hidinput)
{
    int ret;

    ret = winwing_init_led(hdev, hidinput->input);
    hid_err(hdev, "init led done\n");

    if (ret)
        hid_err(hdev, "led init failed\n");

    return ret;
}

static int winwing_raw_event(struct hid_device *hdev,
        struct hid_report *report, u8 *raw_data, int size)
{
    struct winwing_drv_data *data = hid_get_drvdata(hdev);

    if (!data)
        return -EINVAL;

        if (data->remap) {
        int src, dst;
        int index_src, index_dst;
        __u8 mask_src, mask_dst;
        int i = 0;
        while (data->remap[i] < 128) {
            src = data->remap[i++];
            dst = data->remap[i++];
            index_src = src / 8 + 1;
            index_dst = dst / 8 + 1;
            mask_src = 1 << (src % 8);
            mask_dst = 1 << (dst % 8);
            if ((raw_data[index_src] & mask_src) != 0) {
                raw_data[index_dst] |= mask_dst;
            } else {
                raw_data[index_dst] &= ~mask_dst;
            }
        }
        }

    if (size >= 15) {
        /* Skip buttons 32 .. 63 */
        memmove(raw_data + 5, raw_data + 9, 6);

        /* Clear the padding */
        memset(raw_data + 11, 0, 4);
    }

    return 0;
}

static const struct hid_device_id winwing_devices[] = {
    { HID_USB_DEVICE(0x4098, 0xbef0) },  /* Metall rudder */
    {}
};

MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(hid, winwing_devices);

static struct hid_driver winwing_driver = {
    .name = "winwing-rudder",
    .id_table = winwing_devices,
    .probe = winwing_probe,
    .input_configured = winwing_input_configured,
    .raw_event = winwing_raw_event,
};
module_hid_driver(winwing_driver);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

Thanks for your help.

The LED controls created by hid-winwing kernel module can be found in /sys/class/leds/ directory.
For example, this command sets LED brightness on the throttle connected to my desktop:
echo 85 | sudo tee /sys/class/leds/input17577\:\:backlight/brightness

More info on that interface:
https://docs.kernel.org/leds/leds-class.html
I have not found how to enable LED control by sending EV_LED events to that driver.

maybe, but the leds of the rudder pedals are not recognized
